# Clone Windows 10 onto Windows 7 partition?

Tags: disk-cloning

I have a hp laptop running Windows 7 and Windows 10 on an external drive. I swap out the drives when I need one or the other. I was wondering if there was a way to dual boot the two on one drive. More specifically, would it be possible to clone my Windows 10 drive onto a partition on my Windows 7 drive? I have all the installation media but it would mean endless updates and restarts as well as driver downloads, etc. Any and all advice much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly dual-boot Windows 10 and 7 in separate partitions on the same
disk, and there are many sources available on the process, for example
[You can dual-boot Windows 7 with Windows 10, but there's a catch](https://www.pcworld.com/article/3050502/windows/you-can-dual-boot-windows-7-with-windows-10-but-theres-a-catch.html).

However, because of differences in the NTFS implementations and user accounts,
you would be better not letting both of the Windows versions update the same
files.

Comment: I see. So I can’t clone my disk?

Comment: There are products that can clone a Windows partition, even partitions which are not the same size. See for example how to do it with [AOMEI Backupper Standard](https://www.backup-utility.com/windows-10/clone-hard-drive-windows-10-0528.html), but other utilities do exist - [see here](https://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-drive-cloning-software.htm).